# how to dump a single stored procedure from a database

Tags: mysql, backup, stored-procedures, mysqldump

I need to create a dump file that contains a single stored procedure from a database, not all routines.

I've tried something like this:

```
mysqldump -u root -pssmart --skip-triggers --no-create-info --no-data \
    --no-create-db --skip-opt test_fshop SP_ITEM_SALES_REPORT -R \
    > test_fshop_routines.sql
```

Here `test_fshop` is my DB name and `SP_ITEM_SALES` is my SP. I want my SP as .sql file.

Answer (score 5):

## BAD NEWS

You cannot use mysqldump to do this.

## GOOD NEWS

You can use the mysql client. First, find out if the Stored Procedure exists. If it does, then fetch the type of Procedure it is (`PROCEDURE` or `FUNCTION`). Then, issue the `SHOW CREATE` for the Stored Procedure. You will have to strip the top 3 and bottom 3 lines:

```
DBNAME=${1}
SPNAME=${2}
SPFILE=${DBNAME}_${SPNAME}.sql
SPTEMP=${DBNAME}_${SPNAME}.tmp
MYSQL_CONN="-u... -p..."
SQLSTMT="SELECT COUNT(1) FROM mysql.proc WHERE db='${DBNAME}' AND name='${SPNAME}'"
PROC_EXISTS=`mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"${SQLSTMT}" | awk '{print $1}'`
if [ ${PROC_EXISTS} -eq 1 ]
then
    SQLSTMT="SELECT type FROM mysql.proc WHERE db='${DBNAME}' AND name='${SPNAME}'"
    PROC_TYPE=`mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"${SQLSTMT}" | awk '{print $1}'`
    SQLSTMT="SHOW CREATE ${PROC_TYPE} ${DBNAME}.${SPNAME}\G"
    mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"${SQLSTMT}" > ${SPFILE}

    #
    # Remove Top 3 Lines
    #
    LINECOUNT=`wc -l < ${SPFILE}`
    (( LINECOUNT -= 3 ))
    tail -${LINECOUNT} < ${SPFILE} > ${SPTEMP}

    #
    # Remove Bottom 3 Lines
    #
    LINECOUNT=`wc -l < ${SPTEMP}`
    (( LINECOUNT -= 3 ))
    head -${LINECOUNT} < ${SPTEMP} > ${SPFILE}
else
    echo "Stored Procedure ${DBNAME}.${SPNAME} Does Not Exist"
fi
rm -f ${SPTEMP}
```

Here is a sample run:

```
[root@***]# ./GetMyProc.sh common DMSPushers
[root@***]# cat common_DMSPushers.sql
CREATE DEFINER=`pma`@`10.%` PROCEDURE `DMSPushers`()
BEGIN

  DECLARE cntr INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE dealerName VARCHAR(50);
  DECLARE dealerID INT;

  DECLARE done boolean DEFAULT false;
  DECLARE dealers CURSOR FOR SELECT bdd.dealer_id, ta.name FROM `b_dealer__dmsaccount` bdd left join t_dmsaccount ta on bdd.dmsaccount_id = ta.id where ta.dms_type = 1 order by bdd.dealer_id desc;

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done := true;

  OPEN dealers;

  read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH dealers INTO dealerID, dealerName;
        SET cntr = cntr + 1;

    IF done OR cntr > 200 THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

        IF dealerID > 0 AND dealerID < 664 THEN
                IF dealerName IS NULL THEN
                        SET dealerName = '';
                END IF;
                SET dealerName = REPLACE(dealerName,'''','''''');

                -- Does the Database even exist???
                SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(SCHEMA_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = ''D',dealerID,''' INTO @schemaExists');
                PREPARE stmt1 FROM @query;
                EXECUTE stmt1;

                IF @schemaExists > 0 THEN
                        SET @query = CONCAT('INSERT dealers_that_push (dealerID, dealerName, pushDate) SELECT ', dealerID, ',''', dealerName ,''',date FROM D',dealerID,'.contactLog where message like ''%pushed to the DMS%''');
                        PREPARE stmt1 FROM @query;
                        EXECUTE stmt1;
                END IF;

        END IF;

  END LOOP;

  CLOSE dealers;
END
[root@***]#
```

## GREAT NEWS

Here is a script that will dump every Stored Procedure into separate SQL files:

```
MYSQL_CONN="-u... -p..."
SQLSTMT="SELECT COUNT(1) FROM mysql.proc"
PROCCOUNT=`mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"${SQLSTMT}" | awk '{print $1}'`
if [ ${PROCCOUNT} -eq 0 ] ; then exit ; fi
SPLIST=""
for DBSP in `mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"SELECT CONCAT(type,'@',db,'.',name) FROM mysql.proc"`
do
    SPLIST="${SPLIST} ${DBSP}"
done
for TYPEDBSP in `echo "${SPLIST}"`
do
    DB=`echo "${TYPEDBSP}" | sed 's/@/ /' | sed 's/\./ /' | awk '{print $2}'`
    SP=`echo "${TYPEDBSP}" | sed 's/@/ /' | sed 's/\./ /' | awk '{print $3}'`
    SQLSTMT=`echo "SHOW CREATE ${TYPEDBSP}\G" | sed 's/@/ /'`
    SPFILE=${DB}_${SP}.sql
    SPTEMP=${DB}_${SP}.tmp
    echo Echoing ${SQLSTMT} into ${SPFILE}
    mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"${SQLSTMT}" > ${SPFILE}
    #
    # Remove Top 3 Lines
    #
    LINECOUNT=`wc -l < ${SPFILE}`
    (( LINECOUNT -= 3 ))
    tail -${LINECOUNT} < ${SPFILE} > ${SPTEMP}
    #
    # Remove Bottom 3 Lines
    #
    LINECOUNT=`wc -l < ${SPTEMP}`
    (( LINECOUNT -= 3 ))
    head -${LINECOUNT} < ${SPTEMP} > ${SPFILE}
    rm -f ${SPTEMP}
done
ls -l
```

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 2):

I got the following from stack overflow (but lost the link)

```
mysqldump  --compact --no-create-info \
    --where="db='serialize' AND type='PROCEDURE' AND name IN ('sp_abraca_dabra')" \
    --databases mysql --tables proc > outputfile.sql
```

Change "serialize" and "sp_abraca_dabra" to suit your database and stored procedure respectively.

Link is : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7080270

Answer (score 1):

If you want to dump ONLY one procedure from a database, this line should do the trick. It is not the mysqldump utility, but the mysql interactive application itself.

```
mysql --user=root mydb -e "SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE myprocedure;" > myprocedure.sql
```

Here you can read my full answer for Windows and batch:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25629708/488117

Answer (score 0):

No perfect solution, but I wrote this simpler script which gives a usable output (pipe to mysql again )

getproc.sh  SCHEMA  PROC

```
mysql -rBN << !
select concat('
delimiter $
drop procedure if exists ',name,'$
create procedure ',name,' ( ',param_list,' ) ',body,' $
delimiter ;
')
from mysql.proc where db='$1' and name='$2';
!
```

Not tested with fancy character sets, and one may want to add the 'definer' as well...

Comment: note that line feeds and tabs need to be substituted for this to really work. something like sed -i 's/\\t/\t/g'  /mydir/*.sql