# How to create a mysql stored procedure through linux terminal

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

In mysql console we will use the delimiter command to change the delimiter and it is useful to define the procedures. 
I understood the  command   `delimiter` for only the mysql client(client side command).

but  I am using the mysql client which does not have the command `delimiter` 
like `dbslayer`, on this kind of clients how can I define the procedures.

for now consider:

```
create procedure test_pro()
begin
select 'hello pro';
end
```

I tried the following :

```
mysql -u root -pmypass  test < proc_file
```

where  proc_file contains the above procedure;

but that is giving me the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
```

Event I tried the following

```
 create procedure test_pro()
    begin
    select 'hello pro';
    end;
```

(added the trailing semicolon)
but am getting the same error .

Same I am experiencing with the `dbslayer` , if I am able to define the above procedure through terminal I think I should be able to do that through the `dbslayer`

Answer (score 13):

There is no way around it. You must use the `DELIMITER` command. Why ?

If you ever perform a mysqldump of the stored procedures, each stored procedure begins with

```
DELIMITER ;;
```

and ends with

```
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is a post where I mentioned this before : [DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS not included in mysqldump](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4090/drop-procedure-if-exists-not-included-in-mysqldump/4092#4092)

Try dumping one stored procedure with mysqldump and see for yourself

I also wrote some code to do this:

- [how to dump a single stored procedure from a database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34222/how-to-dump-a-single-stored-procedure-from-a-database/34268#34268)
- [Dump only the Stored Procedures in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/dump-only-the-stored-procedures-in-mysql/4089#4089)

As for [the answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/41381/877) posted by [**@altmannmarcelo**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/20227/altmannmarcelo), it directly answers your question (+1 for his answer). Otherwise, mysqldumps could never restore stored procedures.

There are two things you can do to accommodate a new DELIMITER:

## TRY THIS #1

Give the delimiter on the command line itself

```
mysql -u root -pmypass --delimiter="//" test < myproc.sql
```

It is a command line option for the mysql client program

```
[root@****]# mysql --help | grep -i delimiter
  --delimiter=name    Delimiter to be used.
delimiter                         ;
```

## TRY THIS #2

You can write the code into a text file and execute against the text file as [**@altmannmarcelo**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/20227/altmannmarcelo) suggested

```
echo "DELIMITER //" > myproc.sql
echo "create procedure test_pro()" >> myproc.sql
echo "begin" >> myproc.sql
echo "select 'hello pro';" >> myproc.sql
echo "end" >> myproc.sql
echo "//" >> myproc.sql
mysql -u root -pmypass  test < myproc.sql
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: Make sure to use something else than `;;`. Using `//` as in the example here worked.

Answer (score 7):

You need to change the delimiter to create a procedure, otherwise MySQL will try to commit your query on `select 'hello pro';`

Change your procedure to:

```
DELIMITER //
create procedure test_pro()
begin
select 'hello pro';
end
//
```

From [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-programs-defining.html):

> If you use the mysql client program to define a stored program containing semicolon characters, a problem arises. By default, mysql itself recognizes the semicolon as a statement delimiter, so you must redefine the delimiter temporarily to cause mysql to pass the entire stored program definition to the server.

Comment: I am aware of this delimiter in mysql console.
I am looking for different thing.
I have asked that how to create a procedure without logging into the mysql console .
If we perform 
like mysql -u root -ppass db -e "select somecolumn from testtable"
if we perform the above command on linux terminal 
we will get the result for the query specified after -e . it will disconnect after performing query , 
The fact is in that query the delimiter // will not work .

Comment: As @RolandoMySQLDBA says(+1), you can either save the procedure to a file with `DELIMITER` or change it passing the argument `--delimiter` on `mysql` command line.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

Contents of mysqlfile.sql

```
USE `dbschemaname`;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `myprocname`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `dbschemaname`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`myusername`@`%` PROCEDURE `myprocname`(IN myvar VARCHAR(3500))
BEGIN
     DECLARE my_id INT;

     SELECT id INTO veh_id FROM mytable WHERE something = myvar;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

and on the commandline:

```
$ mysql -u user -pmypass dbschemaname < mysqlfile.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but the following might be useful for someone in future:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Started ..."
date
host=localhost
user=dbusername
password=dbpassword
database=databasename

time /usr/bin/mysql --host=$host --user=$user --password=$password --database=$database<<EOFMYSQL
DELIMITER $$
create procedure test_pro()
BEGIN
SELECT 'hello pro';
END$$
DELIMITER ;
SHOW WARNINGS;
SHOW COUNT(*) WARNINGS;
EOFMYSQL

echo "Finished "
date
```

Tested and working against Maria DB.

After it finished you can just call the procedure using:

```
call test_pro();
```

Hope that helps :)